# How can i get column value by header name datagrid in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My code

```
<controls:DataGrid>
 <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
 </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

My model

```
public class InforList
    {
        public String Date { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }
        public String Phone { get; set; }          

    }
```

How can i get value from datagrid by header name="Date" guys

Comment: get it via your model - you should probably post that as well so we can assist

Comment: sorry , editted !!!

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  I see the binding and I see a basic model, not a view-model, so I'm curious.  If you are using MVVM then don't rely on the control to give you the results, allow the control to bind to a command in the view-model and have the logic there where it's simpler. If you're not using MVVM then you'll need to write it out manually.  Surf through the columns, find the one you want, then iterate and add all the values in that column (if that's what you're asking.)

Comment: i mean like this https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1288077 but i can't find it in UWP

Comment: please take a look at [DataGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/group_sort_filter#2-sorting) , DataGrid selectedindexchange event and `e.Column.Tag` may help you.

Comment: My question is based on the problem which i'm stucking now, it look like after sorting like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/group_sort_filter#2-sorting the index has been changed so i need to find another way to search in datagrid because if i use item source to search it will use the old index

Comment: @xdisgood for Search : Did you tested Filter sample that available  [same link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/group_sort_filter#3-filtering) ? just put your model data in observation collection then use Linq queries to achieve your goals.